# Alpine JS Conditional binding issue in Eleventy

Tags: javascript, alpine.js, eleventy

I'm trying to use Alpine to add a conditional class if it's a certain day of the week. I'm making a component for 'Office Hours'. I'm using Eleventy and have a Javascript file that lets me dynamically insert the current date on a page using the tag {{ helpers.currentDay }} for another part of the site and it prints the name of the day. In the component I'm building, I want to be able to change the class if the current day is equal to a specific day.

I tried doing the following:

```
<div class="flex flex-col space-y-1" x-data="today: '{{ helpers.currentDay() }}'">
  <ul class="flex space-x-3">
    <li class="font-bold" :class="'color-green' : today == 'Friday'">Friday</li>
    <li>9am - 5pm</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This Example is because today is actually Friday and I want to be able to see the results. In the developers tools for Alpine I see this in the attached image [screenshot of developers tools for Alpine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Fzq.png).

So it looks like it's pulling the day in correctly? I think I might just have a syntax error but I've tried this a few different ways like

`:class="today == 'Friday' ? 'color-green' : '' "`

Comment: Is there some doc or code for `{{ helpers.currentDay }}` ?

Comment: What I see for `x-data` looks more like `x-data="{ today: '{{ helpers.currentDay() }}' }"` Maybe with the `:class="today == 'Friday' ? 'color-green' : '' "` but I need more input for the helpers part

Comment: @Pompedup the {{ helpers.currentDay() }} is using the nunjucks templating format to pull a function from a javascript file using the Eleventy Data stream. This is a static site generator, where when the site builds, it replaces the {{ helpers.currentDay() }} with the output of the function which is a string with the current day of the week. The idea is that I could match the current day of the week to bind the class. So for example today {{ helpers.currentDay() }} would be replaced with `Friday`. In the Chrome Inspector the following is shown for the source:

Comment: ```<div class="flex flex-col space-y-1" x-data="today: 'Friday'">
  <ul class="flex space-x-3">
    <li class="font-bold" :class="'color-green' : today == 'Friday'">Monday</li>
    <li>9am - 5pm</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: As @Pompedup said: `x-data` must be an object when it's not empty. So after 11ty compiles the template it becomes e.g. `x-data="{ today: 'Friday' }"`.